# Displaying categories from database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this in my category model

```
class Categories extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Then in homecontroller

```
public function index()
{

        $products = Product::paginate(15);
        return View::make('site.index', [
            'products' => $products
        ]);        
}
```

This is working perfectly and showing all products on the page. Now I have added this to the function index()

```
        $categories = Categories::paginate(15);
        return View::make('site.index', [
            'categories' => $categories
        ]);
```

and this in index.blade.php

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
     {{{ $category['category_name'] }}}
@endforeach
```

And I got blank page with error

```
production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: categories' in...
```

What is the problem here and why I can't list categories from database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `index` method you've already return view, so no more code will be executed after return statement.
You should do something like this

```
public function index()
{

    $products = Product::paginate(15);
    $categories = Categories::paginate(15);
    return View::make('site.index', [
        'products' => $products,
        'categories' => $categories,
    ]);    

    // or even shorter
    // return view('site.index', compact('products', 'categories');
}
```

Comment: Yes, now is working. I just started with frameworks at all and still trying to learn them. So  in one function I can return only one view..

Comment: From any function in PHP you can return only once.

Comment: But you can compose views as you wish using nested views or composer, for more info look over the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.